# Field in Field Collection not displaying

Tags: 7, entities

Running Drupal 7.59

I have added a field to a field collection using the Structure->field collections->(collection) menu

I edited a page where the field collection is used, and added content to the field.

The new field is retained when I revisit the edit page, but it does not show up in the field preview, nor when I display the current page.

When I add a field to the structure, do I need to do something else to enable display?

I have no idea how to go about debugging this!

Comment: If you add a new normal/non field collection field, does the same issue occur?

Comment: Yes!  How do I debug this?

Comment: I believe your theme is printing those fields through a custom template file. So check your theme's /templates folder for something like node--[content-type-name].tpl.php. If I am correct, you would have to print the field collection field in here.

Comment: That was it.  I inherited this site from someone else, and the theme is a rats-nest.